# How to fix java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm really new to coding and is stuck on some java code. I've researched this problem, but can't seem to find the answer, or understand what's wrong with my code.

I'm making a program that takes three integer command-line arguments and
prints equal if all three are equal, and not equal otherwise.

My code looks like this

```
public class ThreeInteger {

    public static void main (String[] args){
          int a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
          int b = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
          int c = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);

          if ((a==b) && (b==c) && (a==c)) {
          System.out.println("equal");
          } 

          else {
              System.out.println("not equal");
          } 
    }

}
```

When i try to run i get get this: 
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at ThreeInteger.main(ThreeInteger.java:5)

How do I get rid of this?

Comment: Are you passing three arguments to your program when you run it?

Comment: *"I'm making a program that takes three integer command-line arguments and"* - then I don't pass any ... for whatever reasons.

Comment: I see. Cheers for the quick response!

Answer (score -3):

You must 3 parameter in main while compilation .. because you are trying to access the 3rd element which is not present in array of main.